# Jmeter - Reading data from 'user.properties' into 'user defined variables'

Tags: jmeter

I am trying to use data from user.properties file. The data is defined like:
protocol=https

I tried to use  into 'user defined variables' like:

[image]

prop ${__P(protocol)}

When i call as: 
log.warn("Whole1: " + vars.get("prop"));

the result is always: 1

What should i do in order to get value as 'https'?

Comment: Why not use `props.get("protocol")`?

Comment: If i try props.get("protocol"), my result is: null

Comment: so there's a problem with your property definition

Comment: it is defined like: protocol=https, into 'user.properties' file

Comment: It should work, unless you override/rename property file or override it somehow, add `Property Display` to your GUI to view all existing properties

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Most probably you have previously set the `protocol` property to be `1` hence you're getting that value as properties live as long as JVM lives, remember that you need to **restart JMeter** each time you make a change in the *user.properties* file, apart from this your syntax looks good.

You can also use [-J command-line argument](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#options) in order to override the JMeter property value like:

```
jmeter -Jprotocol=https
```

More information:

- [Configuring JMeter](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#configuring_jmeter)
- [Overriding Properties Via The Command Line](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#override)
- [Apache JMeter Properties Customization Guide](https://blazemeter.com/blog/apache-jmeter-properties-customization/)

Comment: After restarting Jmeter, works fine, using: props.get("protocol")

Answer (score 0):

Try like this ${prop}

Since, you are putting in UDV.

Comment: Still i am getting: 1

Comment: Restart jmeter as suggested by @Dmitri T then check.